# Which one is correct "XYZ movie has released this week." or "XYZ movie has been release this week"?

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice, active-voice

i am confused  between "has been released" and "has released". I don't know which one I should use. Here is the example:-
"XYZ movie has released this week."
"XYZ movie has been released this week."
which one is correct

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is incomplete. *To release* is chiefly a transitive verb and requires an object. The first sentence implies that the XYZ movie has released something that is not mentioned. The second sentence is correct as it is in the passive voice and has a subject and object.

Comment: Xyz is the name of the movie.

Comment: We know that XYZ is a movie title. What MF has explained is that there are verbs like *a dog bites a man* that are active, and there are those like *a man was bitten by a dog* that are passive.